# How can I set the default value (not date) for SBPickerSelector on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

For this picker library [Busta117/SBPickerSelector](https://github.com/Busta117/SBPickerSelector) on iOS, how can I set a default value for the kind `.text` having `numberOfComponents = 2`?

Im currently showing it like:

```
let picker = SBPickerSelector()
picker.delegate = self
picker.numberOfComponents = 2
picker.pickerType = .text
picker.pickerData = [["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
                     Array(repeating: "", count: 13).enumerated().map{"\($0.0) in"}]

picker.pickerId = "height"
picker.doneButtonTitle = "Done"
picker.cancelButtonTitle = "Cancel"

picker.showPickerOver(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `picker.pickerView` contains the `UIPickerView` so you you can:

```
picker.pickerView.selectRow(<row: Int>, inComponent: Int>, animated: Bool)
```